# Apps Script: Change the value of some cells in Last Row

Tags: google-apps-script

This code gives me exactly what I want: the values of the last row. Now I am trying to overwrite/replace these values in some cells in that very same last row. By “*some cells*” I specifically mean 2 cells, where I want to put new values coming from another/good-working function. Any idea how this can be done?

Thank you so much in advance for your help :).

```
function changeCellValueInLastRow() {

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  var data = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function changeCellValueInLastRow(v, col = 1) {
  if (v && col) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET NAME');
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), col).setValue(v);
  }
}
```